# Bypassing character limit on OPENQUERY failing use EXECUTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, t-sql, ssms

I am currently using SQL Server Management Studio 17 to connect to an Oracle database instance and then extract some data and insert it into a SQL Server Table I have.

I have tried doing the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [jerry].[dbo].[purchases]
SELECT * INTO [jerry].[dbo].[purchases] FROM OPENQUERY(OLAP, '

    proprietary sql code

');
```

However the SQL code is about 9500 characters and thus `OPENQUERY` fails, which is supported by [MSDN articles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

I referenced these sites:

- [- MSDN One](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/19022658-6a0c-416c-a524-234bd7c2b05e/openquery-limitation-max-8000-character?forum=transactsql)  [- MSDN Two](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0847ad24-0dfe-4ae1-9788-5516c7830f40/using-openquery-with-variables-in-the-argument?forum=transactsql)

and learned that I can use `EXEC` to accomplish my goal. 
I have tried to implement the following:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'OLAP', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'true'
DECLARE @sqlcode VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sqlcode = 'sql code'


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [jerry].[dbo].[purchases]
EXEC @sqlcode AT OLAP
```

However, I am still getting an `Invalid Syntax near OLAP` error.
I have confirmed that `OLAP` is the correct name from our DBA and other `OPENQUERY` functions work just fine (with much shorter SQL statements).

- I cannot edit the SQL query
- I cannot edit the external OLAP's databases permissions (I am not the DBA nor am I in the security group)

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure but this link has great deal of information about the linked server which you are using, and if you could check it. https://www.sqlshack.com/link-sql-server-oracle-database/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EXEC without parentheses runs a stored procedure.

So try:

```
truncate table [jerry].[dbo].[purchases]

insert into [jerry].[dbo].[purchases]
exec ( @sqlcode ) at olap
```

See [execute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017/)

Comment: Looks like the user does not have permissions to modify the linked server.  Typically a sysadmin would run that command.

Comment: how can I update my table using `EXEC` here, can you edit your answer to show that so I can accept?

Comment: how can I update my table using `EXEC` here, can you edit your answer to show that so I can accept? Currently, this shows me the correct rows but does not create the `[jerry].[dbo].[purchases]` table

Comment: Instead of SELECT .. INTO you just truncate the table and run INSERT ... EXEC

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion @DavidBrowne. Oddly, it tells me I cannot find it or I don't have permissions (which is impossible since I am the one who set it up). But I will keep researching. Sigh... Thank you!!

Comment: If you dropped the table, you'll have to recreate it.